# Looping read.xlsx for reading in multiple sheets and saving them as separate DF´s

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, google-sheets, readxl

I want to read in sheets 3:8 of my excel file and save them separately.

I got something like this:

```
 for (y in 2012:2017){
     save("Year" ,y)<- for (i in 3:8)

{
   read_xlsx("/Users/.../Desktop/Kriminalität.xlsx", sheet = i , skip = 4)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I reformatted the code a bit and I think it shows at least one problem ... what is it that you are trying to do in the now second line?    What name are you trying to save the files to?   Is your goal  to have 6 separate files?

Comment: It isn't clear from your code what you're expected output is.  Do you have individual files for years 2012 - 2017, each with sheets 3 - 8 that need to be read (for a total of 36 sheets)? Or is there just one file where sheets 3 - 8 correspond to the years 2012 - 2017?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want to save 5 sheets as separate dataframes and name them as Year2012,Year2013....Year2017.

Create an empty list and read the sheets as elements.Name these elements accordingly and then unlist to get separate dataframes

```
library(openxlsx)

x=list()

for(i in 3: 8){
x[[i]]=read.xlsx("check.xlsx",sheet = i,colNames = T)
}

names(x)=paste0("Year",c(2012:2017))
list2env(x,envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setwd("your directory to excel ")

library(readxl)

data="Kriminalität.xlsx" # your excel name

n=8 #number of the sheets in your excel

for (i in 3:n){ 
 y=paste("sheet",i,sep="") 
  assign(y, read_xlsx(data, sheet = i ,skip = 4))
}
```

in section `for (i in 3:n)` you could define your sheets to read, for example `for (i in 3:8)` means read sheet3 to sheet8

results for a excel with 3 sheets `for (i in 1:3)`:

[image: results for a excel with 3 sheets]

Comment: thank's a lot ! it really helped me. starting to understand for loops :)